# Want the table head in a Row

Tags: visualforce, datatable

In my datatable  am not able to manage the table head properly. I want them in a Row 
[image]

but i want the as

Mon tue Wed thu fri Sun

My code

```
  <apex:pageBlock >
     <apex:pageBlockSection id="Event_view"  title="Event View" >


          <apex:repeat var="a" value="{!CevtWp}">
          <apex:datatable value="{!a.evLst_W}" columns="3" var="d" Width="700px">
              <apex:column width="300px" >
                  <apex:facet name="header">Time</apex:facet>
                  <apex:outputText value="{!a.startDate_W}"/>
              </apex:column>

              <apex:column width="300px" >
                  <apex:outputText value="{!a.subject_W}"/>
              </apex:column>

           </apex:datatable>               
          </apex:repeat>


     </apex:pageBlockSection>
   </apex:pageBlock>
```

Comment: Could you post your controller code for `CevtWp`?

Answer (score 1):

You have to specify the  number of columns to the pageBlockSection tag. By default it takes the value as 2.